# The Man in the Ocean

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

A man dressed in uniform is lying face down in the ocean with a backpack on. What happened to him?

Comment: idk if im qualified to say this, but is this question kinda broad?

Comment: These kind of questions do really extend our later-thinking abilities. Some of these are simple and require no tangent processes, while others really push the limit. I think this is  valid riddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

> he **jumped out of a helicopter** (or some other aircraft :P) and **tried to open a parachute** (which is supposed to be a backpack I guess...) and it uh...kinda **failed to open**? So he died...whoops.

But, I don't know

> how he was going to survive anyways because he jumped out in the middle of the ocean...like even if the parachute worked...

Answer (score 3):

He is

> **Scuba diving** (most likely surface scuba diving) with a [backpack](https://www.amazon.com/diving-backpacks/b?ie=UTF8&node=3406311) on.
>
>  He's lying face down in order to see underwater, and the uniform in question is, in fact, the diving suit he's wearing.

Comment: Oooo good one I never thought of it that...my first reaction was that he died :P

Comment: me too, but then i realized they never specified the person's status :P

Comment: wait wat...OP just accepted? I'm so confused now...

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe (just to add some silliness to the otherwise grim-looking situation)

> a sailor on shore leave got blackout drunk and passed out in the McDonald’s ball pit.

Comment: this solution is clearly the best one